# State of the art balloon materials

Tags: materials, balloons

What are the state of the art balloon materials used for high altitudes ascending (top of troposphere, approximately 50 km)?

Are there new material improvements likely in the next future? If so which are likely candidates?

Comment: The best ballon materials would not allow to leave the upper atmosphere and to enter space.

Comment: This might be more suited for https://aviation.stackexchange.com which is supposed to be competent in aerostats

Answer (score 3):

> Standard NASA scientific balloons are constructed of polyethylene
>   film; the same type material used for plastic bags. This material is
>   only 0.002 centimeters (0.0008 inches) thick, about the same as an
>   ordinary sandwich wrap.

[Source](https://www.csbf.nasa.gov/balloons.html)

Comment: https://www.csbf.nasa.gov/pictures/NASA_standards_metric.png